# How To Install pyodbc Drivers On Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I'm currently writing a Flask program that executes as an Azure Web App, and I'm trying to implement a simple login system.  The login data (ids, passwords, etc.) are located in the 'Users' table of an Azure SQL database.  The recommended way as far as I can tell to connect to said database is using `pyodbc` , which doesn't work as it returns an error stating that the necessary drivers are not there.  In fact, there are no drivers returned when I use `pyodbc.drivers()`.

My question is how do I install the necessary drivers to the server? I've currently tried uploading the drivers as a file to the Bash client, but this has not yet worked (it is possible I'm doing it wrong as I'm unfamiliar with Linux). I've also attempted to see if it was possible to connect without the drivers, but that has also been unsuccessful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.